# Convert Digit Time to seconds

Tags: php, time, digit, date-conversion

How can I convert a digit time into seconds?

I need to compare the time so I though that it is easier to convert the digit time to seconds and compare the seconds later on.

for example:

```
00:00:33
00:01:33
02:01:33
```

Comment: What do you mean by "digit time"?

Comment: @Panda - the solution on that page while compact, is subject to inaccuracies due to the first `strtotime()` time being slightly different than the second `strtotime()` as it is processed in sequential order.  It is good in most cases where precision isn't a priority and where server load is minimal.

Comment: Lots of answers, but no one questioning *why* you want to do this. Time strings are already comparable as they are. Equality and comparison operators already work as expected when applied to the strings themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom parser if you are looking for precise seconds from that format.

Something like this should do the trick :

```
echo hhmmss2seconds("18:24:35");

function hhmmss2seconds($time) {
    $digits = explode(":", $time);
    $seconds = 0;
    $seconds = $seconds + intval($digits[0]) * 3600; // hours
    $seconds = $seconds + intval($digits[1]) * 60; // minutes
    $seconds = $seconds + intval($digits[2]); // seconds    
    return $seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `strtotime()`. This converts "digit time" to Unix time.

```
$time_in_seconds = strtotime('00:00:33');
```

Comment: strange if I do this $test = strtotime(00:00:33);
echo $test . '<br>'; I get an unexpected ":"

Comment: hmm I do not get an error now but it returns me this : 1483570833

Comment: The parameter of `strtotime()` needs to be a string so like this: `echo $test = strtotime("00:00:33");`

Comment: I modified it so it is encapsulated in quotes, however the result of strtotime is incorrect. [proof it is not valid](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bcbf099cd6927f664aebb6f4fbe7372d50de9afe)

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/42686de4f5b1550086fa75c09c2fcabd12051263

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo strtotime("1970-01-01 00:00:11  UTC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This its working

```
 <?php
    function time_to_seconds($time) { 
        list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $time); 
        return ($h * 3600) + ($m * 60) + $s; 
    }
    echo time_to_seconds("00:00:33");
    echo time_to_seconds("00:01:33");
    echo time_to_seconds("02:01:33");

    ?>
```

Thank you..